# Url to download specific file using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have xampp based application... Content off app is on this location:

```
/var/www/mysite.com/
```

I want to create link that looks like this:

```
mysite.com/documents/3C1791F6132D4B8B5AAB235B4AE6FA67
```

Can I do that with `.htaccess` (and mod_rewrite) so clicking on that link would cause downloading of a file that is on one of those two locations:

```
/var/www/files/document.pdf
```

or if that is impossible, here is a second location:

```
/var/www/mysite/storage/files/document.pdf
```

I also don't want a browser to open the file, but to start the download.

P.S. Everything here is planned to be hardcoded. It's "one time only" thing.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: If its hardcoded why don't you just move the file to mysite.com/documents/3C1791F6132D4B8B5AAB235B4AE6FA67? programmers always use the path of least resistance, so is there a reason you need the htacces?

Comment: @starkeen So far I had file and application ;) I tried to google a solution, read some of .htaccess documentation, but it didn't help much

Comment: @Starmixcraft Yes, but then 3C1791F6132D4B8B5AAB235B4AE6FA67 is going to be filename, and I want to call it document.pdf... also, I would like apache to serve a file that's on location different than application..

Comment: @starkeen acctually so far I tried this:
RewriteRule ^3C1791F6132D4B8B5AAB235B4AE6FA67$ /storage/test.pdf [L]
but I'm lost filename and i had to use location that i don't like (but i can live with location problem)

Comment: @inemanja But if you internally rewrite it the browser will still use 3C1791F6132D4B8B5AAB235B4AE6FA67 as the filename, there is HTML code to tell the browser the correct filename

Comment: @Starmixcraft OK, if I cannot do it only using htaccess, I'll accept a solution that uses HTML...